# Connecting a Jupyter Notebook to a Sever without an External IP

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cloud, remote-server

I want to set up a connection to between a Jupyter Notebook and a remote server that does not have an external IP address. Is this possible to do? And, how? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to connect to a remote Jupyter Server or make your jupyter notebook to some external server that has no public IP address? (to fetch some data, for example)

Comment: @mkostelac I want to connect a local Jupyter notebook on my computer to an external server that has no public IP address - exactly, to fetch data, and run some big data using the server but from my laptop. thank you.